# How to diff metadata from Github with my managed package

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, developer-org

SFDX looks promising for this, but I'm confused and am running out of time. Your help is appreciated. It seems this could do what I need... 
sfdx force:source:diff

But it appears to only work on single files (and not directories), true? I would test it with the force-app/main/default directory in VSCode (screenshot below), but I'm currently erring with...
"ERROR running force:source:diff:  Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance." -- Does this mean I need a scratch org instead of a regular Partner Dev Org?

Please advise.

I brought this metadata in from a Github Repo

[image]

I have a Partner Dev Org with a package in it. It should be ahead of the repo, as the guy working in the org says he added a few things to the latest version of the package.

How do I do a diff my Dev Org's latest package version with our Github Repo directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to achieve this

- Create a different branch for holding whats their in org. Checkout locally using `git checkout -b <branchname>`
- Install [SalesforceDX CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli).
- Authenticate to your Partner Developer org using `sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultusername`
- Retrieve metadata from your org to the new branch using `sfdx force:source:retrieve --packagenames=<nameofpackage>`
- Create a [Pull Request](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request) between the branches and you should see the diff

Edit.

Note that you will get .dup files as [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_convert_mdapi.htm). Extract package.xml and retrieve using `force:source:retrieve` to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you Mohith (and all who replied). I followed your steps smoothly. After the retrieve, I must have 100 untracked files, all with .dup at the end. It seems .dup means they are duplicates? Duplicates of what? Currently, when I push these files to Github, it shows all these files as net new. They are not - it only sees them as new because of the appended .dup

Comment: I wonder about compatibility between the metadata on remote master (also in the local branch you asked me to create) and the metadata in the package which I retrieved to this local branch. I guess the two need to use the same format, right? Do I need to consider mdapi?

Comment: What format is their in your local ? You can inter connect from mdapi to source format and vice versa

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_convert_mdapi.htm Check here on how to handle .dup file

Comment: This solution worked. The retrieve just looked really strange in git. Git status had 100 or so Untracked files, all ending with .dup   On closer look, also under Untracked was a single Directory of the same name as my Managed Package. When I did git add on that only, I got what appears to be only the changed files. I committed only those, and left out all the .dup files. It seems that "sfdx force:source:retrieve --packagenames=<nameofpackage>" gets both a file with the changed files, and it marks all others as duplicates. Not an elegant way to do things. LMK your thoughts.

Comment: @RyanMcNeely What was your source format in your git ? mdapi or uses force-app/ dx format ?

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: if it has package.xml in src folder then mdapi else if it uses force-app/main, it means DX Source format ?

Comment: Unfortunately the PR did not pass. It just has a bunch of added files. It doesn't show any changes within the files.

Comment: @RyanMcNeely Did you compare your .dup file and what was there in your file ? Also other option is to do an mdapi:retrieve and use package name parameter to retrieve it

Comment: Ok, the screenshot above fits your description of DX Source format, as it has force-app/main/default. That's coming from the Repository.

Comment: I tried mdapi, the one that retrieves a .zip right? If you will, could you provide the steps here and I'll run them now.

Comment: Yes once you retrieve the file it will be a zip file and then you extract it

Comment: Your base answer here was spot on Mohith. Use Github's Pull Request diff to compare code in the Packaging Org with the GH Repo. I had a number of other issues outside the scope of this specific need to diff.

Comment: "Retrieve metadata from your org to the new branch using sfdx force:source:retrieve --packagenames=<nameofpackage>" --> Instead of this, I did "sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipkg -p PackageName" --> Inside the zip, I found a package.xml with the exact set of components in my PackageName. Then, I did a source retrieve with that package.xml.

Comment: Above comments about .dup and untracked files are no longer issues. The untracked files turned out to be files in the Packaging Org that should be in the Repo. The Repo was just that far behind Packaging Org.

Comment: Ya that’s good workaround to avoid the dup files. I am not a big fan of dup feature but it’s there for a reason to avoid overwriting.

Comment: Because your branch was far off and lot of duplicates I guess what you did to get package.xml and retrieve again makes sense. Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you separate them into 2 directories you could potentially run `git diff --no-index some/path other/path >> some_filename` credit to: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945988/6200445

Comment: the OP is asking about retrieve from the package that exists in salesforce org to his local and and comparing to what is there today in local. This answer does not look like it will help

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone the GitHub repository and `cd` into the directory where it was cloned.
2. Authenticate to your Partner Developer org using sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultusername
3. Pull in changes from the developer org with `sfdx force:source:retrieve --packagenames=<nameofpackage>`
4. Run `git diff` to view changes on the command line

Answer (score -1):

Here's a bash script I made to help retrieve metadata from orgs:

Params:

1 - org

2 - cmdt object name without namespace & __mdt

3 - (**optional**) specify metadata records by developer name, comma delimited

```
pull_cmdt() {
    if [ -z "$3" ]; then 
        json=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -u $1 -q "SELECT DeveloperName FROM $2" --json)
        metadata=""
        for row in $(echo "${json}" | jq -r '.result.records[] | @base64'); do
            _jq() {
                echo "${row}" | base64 --decode | jq -r "${1}"
            }

        name=$(_jq '.DeveloperName')
        metadata+="CustomMetadata:$2.$name,"
        done
        metadata=${metadata%?}
    else
        delimiter=","
        declare -a array=($(echo $3 | tr "$delimiter" " "))
        metadata=""
        for x in "${array[@]}"; do
            metadata+="CustomMetadata:$2.$x,"
        done
        metadata=${metadata%?}
    fi
    sfdx force:source:retrieve -u $1 -m $metadata   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This script doesn't appear to address this question as asked, which is about metadata in general, not CMDT records.